# I want to write the AdUnitId from String?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob

> I want to write the `AdUnitId` from String

```
  MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
            }
        });
        AdView adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-8580705205581022/6543518491");
        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can go into your strings.xml in the values directory and add
`<string name="app_unit_id" translatable="false">ca-app-pub-8580705205581022/6543518491</string>`
and in your code you just write `adView.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.app_unity_id));`

**You dont need the `translateable="false"` if you dont use localization**

This should work :D